# Issue with git commit and branch

Tags: git, github, version-control

I had an issue with pull request (PR) which ended up being rejected. What happened was that there were some redundant files committed to the branch which should not have. The actual files committed were fine but these spurious files got the approver confused and rejected. So after some deliberation I took this action

```
 1. git checkout staging, went to clean one
 2. git pull
 3. git checkout -b "new_branch"
```

Then I just copied over two amended files (where they were saved outside of git directory) and then I did

```
 1. git status
 2. git branch
 3. git add .
 4. git -m "some comment"
 5. git push -u origin new_branch
```

I suspect that when I created the branch I was supposed to be working on before, I accidentally edited some other files and did not check git status and "git add ." properly. So I want to avoid these mistakes. So just to clarify

1. When we create a new branch - only amend the files needed. Any other file accidentally altered will be picked up at git add .. time?
2. Always check with git status before adding to local git (on a Linux host)
3. if you want to ensure that correct files are added with git add, get the list of files amended with "git status" and use git add "filename" only (named files)
4. How can I remove a file added with git add accidentally from local git?
5. I tried to delete the old branch with git -D old_branch but git stated cannot delete this branch as it is committed?
6. what would be the best option to remove this old_branch from github itself as it is redundant and from my local git directory.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Git stores all its history as diff information.

Git reset will undo git add for files that are staged but not committed.

If you have already committed to a local repository, then you can use git filter-branch to rewrite git history. Once you push to GitHub, policy is that official git history cannot be rebased.

- https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository

You could alternatively use git rm to delete an errant file and then commit it as a deletion. File will still be visible in git history.

Creating a new branch is also an option, which might allow you to selectively cherry-pick commits to replay from the errant branch.

To delete a branch on GitHub, you may need to login via the website and do it that way.

Comment: Actually, each Git commit is a *full snapshot*, not a diff. The internal storage format for a commit object lists a tree object; the tree object lists sub-trees and blobs. These correspond to Linux directories and inodes. The "inodes" (blobs) are full snapshots. If the same content appears in commit c123456 and then again later in c789abc, the blob gets "hard linked" into both commits. There is a level *below* the object storage level ("pack files") that uses deltas, but that's separate from (and later than) committing.

Comment: To some extent, this internal storage format is irrelevant: Git *could* store diffs (as Mercurial does) and still behave the same way. (Mercurial doesn't always store diffs, either, sometimes it "gives up" and stores a new copy.) However, Git encourages programmers to peek into the internals, to the tree and blob-object levels, at various times, and when they do, they'll "see" snapshots. So it's best to stick with snapshots, since that's what they are and how they're presented.

Comment: Thank you @torek for your points. However, my question as a user of git is with regards to points I raised namely how to about not repeating the mistake that I did.  What git commands will help me rectify any pitfalls.

Comment: @MichTalebzadeh: I'm afraid I didn't (and still don't) understand your original posting. In particular the phrase "went to clean one" makes no sense to me. I just made the comment on James McGuigan's answer, that the storage format is snapshots, as a general comment.

Comment: @torek: what I meant was that I went to staging branch and pulled the repo from the GitHub as is. Just to clarify when you are at root directory on local and you already have existing some directories and have performed a pull request before  those existing directories (some amended etc.)  will be overwritten by the new pull from GitHub so you are back at clean start. cheers

Comment: @MichTalebzadeh: That's ... not how Git works. Git is about *commits;* you `git push` commits to your GitHub fork (if you have one). GitHub will create or update a PR based on the reachable commits, as found from both your PR branch-tip commit and the "base branch" tip commit. The PR proposes to add the same commits (merge), or copies of those commits ("rebase and merge"), or one commit that has the same effect as merging those commits ("squash and merge"), with the actual final action, if any, up to whoever clicks the big green MERGE or XYZ-AND-MERGE button.

Comment: Running `git pull` from a local repository means: *run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command of my choice* where your choice is between `git merge` or `git rebase`. These are also all about commits.

Comment: Another point that I like it to be clarified, when one does git checkout <branch> any changes made will be associated with that branch. git status will show what has changed. If I go and edit another file unrelated (not the one I am supposed to be changing), it will be picked up as well. In short any changes will be attributed to change under that branch. So if I do a git add . and git commit -m I will end up with all files amended picked up under that branch?